# How to disable wireframe for a second 3D view when in edit mode?

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, wireframe

When I enter Edit mode, all 3d views show me wireframe. I want my extra 3D view to show me no wireframe when I enter Edit mode. It is possible in 3ds max by reference copy.
[image: 3D view, current and desired look]

Comment: "Wireframe" mode is toggles with Z. What you're trying to do is have a window with and without *edit mode* enabled, which is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for repl, David. Is there any way to see my object without wireframe while im in edit mode? In 3ds max there is a reference copy, which doesnt show any wireframe when the original object is in Edit poly mode. Thats usefull to see how object smooths on the fly.

Comment: You can use a mirror to obtain that. Same principle as this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56378/subdivided-unsubdivided-linked-split-screen/56383#56383

Comment: In Edit mode you can un-tick _Edges_ from the _Mesh Display_ section of the right hand panel. Edges will still show in Wireframe and Solid shading but not in Texture and Material. It's on a per-object basis tho, so you'll have to un-tick it for each one.

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround for achieving such a work-space might be to make use of the 'Render preview' option in viewport shading. Given that the speed at which the window updates will depend upon the complexity of your scene and your system specs. But it could be useful as it does hide the vertice/edge/face data that can be seen in edit mode. Here's a screenshot of a similar scene:

[image]