# Independent Edit/Object mode in splitscreen

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, edit-mode, object-mode

When I split screen in two and switch *Edit/Object mode*, they both change.
How to change just one?

The intention here is:

- use one to modelling with numkey view with transparent wireframe
- and the other to see the progress in perspective, with solid mesh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two 3d view windows: one in edit mode, one in object mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66693/two-3d-view-windows-one-in-edit-mode-one-in-object-mode)

Comment: A trick to do something equivalent: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56378/subdivided-unsubdivided-linked-split-screen/56383#56383

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switching to *Edit mode* per-viewport isn't currently possible in Blender.

According to [this rightclickselect.com request](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Tjfbbc/) this probably won't be implemented in the near future, since it's *"fundamentally incompatible with the way Blender handles objects"*.

<sub>(I'd like make this a more 'proper' answer with gifs and lists, but in this case....)</sub>

Edit: Thank you @Lemon for your gif services

[image]

Comment: Here you are https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrRIC.gif ... ; )