# Display different object visibilities/modifiers in different viewports?

Tags: 3d-view

I'm working on this model's eyelashes and using a mask modifier to hide the rest of her mesh. Is it possible for me to either have one pane in Object/other in Edit mode, or have one show the eyelashes alone and the other show the whole mesh? Thanks!

E: Old questions ([a](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66693/two-3d-view-windows-one-in-edit-mode-one-in-object-mode), [b](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200428/independent-edit-object-mode-in-splitscreen), [c?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56378/subdivided-unsubdivided-linked-split-screen/56383#56383)) seem to indicate Option 1 isn't possible. Is this still true?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mask modifier, no.  Modifier settings are set for all viewports.  But there are things you can do here.

What you can do here is separate the eyelashes to a new object, then put them in a different collection than the rest of the mesh.  Then, you can enable local collections on one or both of your viewports (in sidebar/view) so that you can see different collections in each viewport; or, you could just / local view the eyelashes in one viewport, which basically just hides everything unselected from a single viewport only until you toggle it back off with / again.

Another option here, for when you can't separate things to different objects, is to use Cycles so that you can use a rendered preview in one window.  Hidden vertices/faces/etc are still shown in a Cycles rendered preview, so you can hide bits of a mesh in one, solid-view viewport, and still see the rest of the mesh in the other viewport.

Worst case scenario, you can duplicate a mesh and surface deform it (modifier) from something you're editing.  That will give you an object, representing your mesh, displayable even in solid; either can be isolated with local collections or local view.  But it's more work to set up than you want.

Comment: It took me a moment to realize you meant the forward slash key, in which case I do know how to do that, but I had forgotten to separate the eyelashes off first. Thanks! Didn't know about the Cycles method either! Wrt "enable local collections", is the sidebar bit just the long (not hotkey) way to do what the forward slash does? Is it the same as checking a collection on/off? And wrt Cycles, do I need a camera/light source to get things to show up?

Comment: @Nintendraw no, it's not quite the same thing.  It's based on collections rather than selections, you can use collection visibility hotkeys if any exist in your interface setup, and you can use local draw on top of it.  With Cycles, you will need a light source (or world).  My startup file is 2 viewports, with local collections, one with overlays disabled, and with world nodes setup, so I end up using a lot of these techniques together pretty naturally.